# How to send notification via bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth

I am running a Grocerry shop, I want to send offer notification via bluetooth to all my customer who enters my shop. If a customer comes within a range of 10 meter near cash counter auto offer notification should trigger. I don't have any idea about how it works. Can any one help me.

Comment: To achieve communication via bluetooth, don't devices have to be paired?

Comment: If that were possible without any prior action from the user, we would be spammed by notifications everywhere we walk... While definitely possible, this requires the user to do something beforehand, usually downloading an app.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with BLE beacons. These are low power BLE devices that run in (unidirectional) advertising mode and thus can transmit (advertising) messages (called attributes) which are not crypto-secured and readable by every BLE enabled mobile device without pairing required.

But on the mobile side, you would need to write an App that detects these beacons and you would need your customer to activate this App when they are in your shop.